# BeanELResolver @Override getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property)

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, el

I have

```
public class ExtendedBeanELResolver extends BeanELResolver {
private static final Pattern regExpDn = Pattern.compile("PLMN-PLMN/\\w+.\\d+(.*)");
@Override
public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property)
   try {

    // remake DIST.NAME appearance
    if (property.equals("dn") && base instanceof Alarm && ((Alarm) base).getCustomer().getNameEng().equalsIgnoreCase("mts")) {

    String dn = null;
    try {
        dn = ((Alarm) base).getDn();
        Matcher mtch = regExpDn.matcher(dn);
        mtch.find();
        ((Alarm) base).setDn(mtch.group(1));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // logger.error("error in dn - " + dn);
    } finally {
        return super.getValue(context, base, property);
    }
    }
}
```

for change some visible values in object depending on some conditions. I do not want to change value if this called from jsf `<ui:param name="fullDistName" value="#{alarm.dn}" />`
How i can get id of component from which this EL called?
sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current JSF component by programmatically evaluating `#{component}` or by invoking [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29).

```
UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
// ...
```

Please note that this tight-couples your EL resolver to JSF.